# R: How to select "and" and "or" at once

Tags: r

I tried to select some columns by using R, but I don't know how to type select "condition A and condition B" or "condition.

```
EXAMPLE= read_spss("data13.sav") %>%
```

select(starts_with("A"), -ends_with("z") | starts_with("PP"))

Also, if I change | into , it works. However, I want to select columns starts with only upper case of "PP", but it also selects "pp".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use `matches`

```
read_spss("data13.sav") %>%   
       select(matches("^(A|PP).*[a-y]$"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also set ignore.case = F

i.e.

```
    read_spss("data13.sav") %>%   
    select(starts_with("A"), -ends_with("z"), starts_with("PP", ignore.case = F))
```